# How to prevent Google from accessing protected content

Tags: security, search, googlebot

I am seriously worried, because Google has somehow indexed a page on my website that is supposedly protected to make it invisible to non-signed in users.

The page is protected by reading a cookie which contains a hash of the user's session. If the hash decrypts to a valid user, the page is displayed. If it does not, the server returns an http error 401 (Access Denied).

On the page that Google indexed, I have verified (using an incognito window) that the 401 error is returned properly and that no data is displayed. However, Google was somehow able to read it, because there is a title showing in its search results.

But it really bothers me that Google was able to read this at all. The only possibility I can think of is that they scraped the page from the browser of a logged in user who had legitimate access, or at the very least used their cookie.

I have since added an extra line to the header:

```
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow'>
```

I don't really know if this will help.

Are there any other actions that I should be taking to give the maximum protection against Google indexing things it's supposedly barred from? Are there any good ways of testing the page to make sure that it's not visible to Google in any way?

(btw I'm not including a URL because the relevant page will soon be approved and therefore become legal to view)

Answer (score 0):

I think Google indexed not the page itself, but the links pointing to it from other pages.